# How to save a game that doesn't have a save feature at all?

Tags: emulation, windows-xp, knight-of-knights

There is an old Windows XP game that I found after many years and wanted to play it again. The game is called "Knight of Knights" by Tomoshibi.
I managed to find a way to run this 3D game on my modern Windows 10 and it runs perfectly.
The problem is, this game does not have any form of saving feature. And just to tell how bad that problem is:

1. If you close the game, you need to start over.
2. If you die once, you need to start over.
3. Even if you just go back to the main menu, you need to start over.

In emulators there is the "save state" function that allow you to save in any game regardless if it is supported in-game or not. I know that doing save state in Windows 10 is not really an option.
Since it's a very old game from Windows XP era, I would like to ask if there is any way to add a save feature to a Windows game.
Maybe running it the same way you run an emulator to isolate it from my main Windows system. Or just getting a mod that give me an option to save. This is a very obscure and unknown game, so there isn't any community that created mods for it.

So how should I go about it?

Comment: This is how roguelike are supposed to be, deal with it.

Comment: If by "dealing with it" you mean modding the game or performing a work around to fix that problem, then yes I will do that.

Comment: Games that are meant to be beat in a single session have only one option, leave the PC on.

Comment: I guess it could be meant to be like that. 
But nobody knows really. 
The game most updated version is 0.5. Means it was never reached the final 1.0 version. 
It is possible things would be different if the game was not discontinued. 
Despite all that the game is really fun. So I am just trying to find a way to make the single player experience better by having this option. 
I am used to use mods in most of my single player games. 
This game sadly does not have any community. So I will need to find a solution myself.

Comment: Run it in a virtual machine and save the machine state?

Comment: "Save the machine state" aka make a snapshot. It's basically the VM equivalent for an emulator's "save state". Alternatively, you could prepare an old laptop and put it to standby by closing the lid. Note that neither of these solutions are guaranteed to work. The game could very well crash upon loading the snapshot or waking up the laptop.

Comment: Thank you guys. 
The snapshot method might work for saving the game.  
The laptop might work for closing the game down. But it won't solve the issue of accidentally returning to main menu or dying. 

So I  will look for options to create a VM that will be able to run games. 
I tried VMware and Virtual Box but sadly they do not support gaming and using the GPU. So maybe using something like KVM or something similiar to get this done.